# new DateTime('2016-04-01 00:00:00') returns '2016-04-01 12:00:00

Tags: php, datetime

This is probably a no-brainer, but I can't see the solution.  I have the following code:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

The output is:

```
2016-03-14 12:00:00
```

I have tried to change timezones, set the timezone, leave it off.  The output never changes.  What gives?  I want the output to read "2016-03-14 00:00:00".

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `H` as it is for 24 hour time and `h` is 12 hour time.  12:00:00 is 12am or 00:00:00:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was going to be something very simple, and it was driving me crazy!

Comment: @h.jim You should accept the answer if it did the trick for you :) !

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

> h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
>
> H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

`h` is for 12-hour clock (AM/PM), so your pattern lacks `a` or `A` to be complete:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s a');
```

would give you `2016-04-01 12:00:00 am`.

If you want full 24-hrs clock, you need to use `H` instead:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which would give expected `2016-04-01 00:00:00`.

[Here is the documentation for supported placeholders](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you can use with `format()`.

Answer (score 1):

As said, `h` is for 12-hour clock format , and `H` for 24-hour clock format. By changing this letter, your date will format as you wish.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-14 00:00:00');
echo $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Here's a list of format that you can use for DateTime object in PHP ([Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time))

```
Day of Month
____________
d   | Numeric, with leading zeros   01–31
j   | Numeric, without leading zeros    1–31
S   | The English suffix for the day of the month   st, nd or th in the 1st, 2nd or 15th.

Weekday
_______
l   | Full name  (lowercase 'L')    Sunday – Saturday
D   | Three letter name Mon – Sun

Month
______
m   | Numeric, with leading zeros   01–12
n   | Numeric, without leading zeros    1–12
F   | Textual full  January – December
M   | Textual three letters Jan - Dec

Year
____
Y   | Numeric, 4 digits Eg., 1999, 2003
y   | Numeric, 2 digits Eg., 99, 03

Time
____
a   | Lowercase am, pm
A   | Uppercase AM, PM
g   | Hour, 12-hour, without leading zeros  1–12
h   | Hour, 12-hour, with leading zeros 01–12
G   | Hour, 24-hour, without leading zeros  0-23
H   | Hour, 24-hour, with leading zeros 00-23
i   | Minutes, with leading zeros   00-59
s   | Seconds, with leading zeros   00-59
T   | Timezone abbreviation Eg., EST, MDT ...
Full Date/Time
c   | ISO 8601  2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
r   | RFC 2822  Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200
```