# Unix timestamps giving distant future year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have several time-stamps returned from a JSON call.
I need to save these a MySQL db.

I have tried to echo them here.

```
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s", 1460132362766) . "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s", 1460133219681) . "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s", 1460133397608) . "<br>";
```

but the results are

> 48239-10-03 3:59:26
>
> 48239-10-13 2:01:21
>
> 48239-10-15 3:26:48

I thought the proper time-stamp format for data type of timestamp in MySQL  `Y-m-d G:i:s`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not seconds, but milliseconds. Divide by 1000.

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT! that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is timestamp in milliseconds which is `1000` times bigger. Just simply do:

```
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s", 1460133397608/1000) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I use G or H for the hours?

Comment: `G` is for hours 0, 1, 2 to 23 without zero. `H` is for hours 00, 01, 02 to 23 with leading zero. So it's up to you to decide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433060/new-datetime2016-04-01-000000-returns-2016-04-01-120000/36433550#36433550    If you want the possible format